# Is it possible to ignore a laravel-data object property when converting to a model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-data

I am using `spatie/laravel-data` to work with some data that eventually gets inserted into the database.

One of the things I need to do is sum up and average some things while I'm doing calculations, and I have (maybe unwisely) stored the running sum as a property (let's call it `$myDataObject->runningTotal`) on my Laravel-data model. Every other property can directly be mapped to a Database column.

At the end I've been doing a `MyEloquentModel::insert($myDataCollection->toArray());` command, but now that I've added this `runningTotal` property, I get an error because Eloquent tries to insert to a column that doesn't exist.

I'd like to ignore that property altogether when transforming my laravel-data object to an Eloquent model, but I can't see anyway to do this.

Comment: I don't know the package but if they are acting like a Model in some way you could try to `makeHidden` that particular field on the Collection, but not sure how they are implementing their `toArray` ... in a regular Model you can make things hidden and they won't be part of the serialization

Comment: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-data/v3/as-a-resource/lazy-properties   maybe that page will help? talks about including or excluding properties

Answer (score 0):

You can define in your DTO a custom function which filters out `runningTotal`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Data;

use Spatie\LaravelData\Data;


class SomeData extends Data
{
    public function __construct(
        public string $someData,
        public int $runningTotal,
    ) {
    }

    public function someData(): array
    {
        return $this->except('runnigTotal')->toArray();
    }
}
```

Then you called as so:

```php
MyEloquentModel::insert($myDataCollection->someData())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just unset the attribute before submission with:

```
unset($myDataCollection->runningTotal);
```

It is not a Laravel way but this uses PHP's built in method.